# Calculated member in schema workbench for Date - Year - month

Tags: pentaho, olap-cube, mondrian

Hello I am using Pentaho user console and schema workbench as a schema designer. For the dimensions of year, month and date I was using three different columns in my table up till now, But now I get to read a lot about calculatedMember in OLAP. But I am not getting how to use it for date datatype.

For an example, If I have only one column in my table which has datatype date and I want three different levels in my Cube like Year, Month and Date which can be derived by only this column. How can I achieve this??

Comment: One should not Calculate Date Dimensions on the fly! Disk space is cheap so just generate a time dimension for the next year and you are done with that task. This will be much more performant than calculating dates on the fly!

Answer (score 0):

Use calculator step of pentaho schema workbench(kettle)
by this you can differentiate the date as per your requirement.

refer [this](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Calculator) link